# How to put a dot on a circle so it's a part of it in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, paint, geometry

So I want to put a dot on a circle. I don't want it centered I want it for example in the right corner of the circle but I want it to be a part of the circle not just another circle placed on top of this one. The reason I want it this way is to show the Rotation Transition of the circle more clearly. How do make this happen?

Comment: Why not? One pane, in this place your main circle, place in your main circle, find position which you need to place your dot( second circle) And rotate this circle from XY of second circle? What are you searching for?

Comment: The circle needs to roll from one side of the window to another. But you can't really see the circle rotating it just looks like it's dragging to the other side. That's why I want the dot to be placed on the circle so you can clearly see the circle rotating while it moves

Comment: You can try to fill your circle with gradient, to view rotation, is it a solution?)

Comment: Define "corner of a circle"...

Answer (score 2):

You could put the `Circle`s in a `Group` and rotate that group instead of the `Circle`:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100);

    Circle dot = new Circle(20, 30, 10, Color.RED);

    Group group = new Group(circle, dot);
    group.setLayoutX(100);
    group.setLayoutY(200);

    Pane root = new Pane(group);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

    RotateTransition transition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), group);
    transition.setByAngle(360);
    transition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    transition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    transition.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```